# Spring Boot REST Resource Changes not Applying

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-rest

I have a very simple Spring Boot application, that consists of an `Order` and a `JpaRepository` `@RepositoryRestResource`:

```java
@Entity
public class Order {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long recordId;

    @Length(max = 64)
    private String orderType;
    .....
}
```

```java
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository<Order, Long>, 
    QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Order> {
}
```

I had recently changed the field `orderKind` to `orderType`. I made sure that the database had been updated. However, on the endpoints, the change isn't applying. It still expects/returns `orderKind`.

I ruled out any IDE issues by cleaning the project, deleting any generated sources, and running directly from the command line, to no luck.

Also verified, and `QOrder.java` that gets generated also had `orderType` defined correctly.

Comment: Please edit your question to include your _endpoints_. What content are you returning? JSON? Are you using Jackson or some other library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While writing this, discovered the problem was trivial. When I refactored the field name, I forgot to update the getter and setter for that field, such that they still read:

```java
public String getOrderKind() {
    return orderType;
}

public void setOrderKind(String orderKind) {
    this.orderType = orderKind;
}
```

Me being new to spring boot didn't realize it was the methods that define the API, which in hindsight seems obvious, since the fields are private.